# Cannot access req.body, even when using body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get my login functionality up and running, but i am unable to access the req.body object.

When i first encountered the issue, the post route was not even getting triggered (console.log was not showing at all in terminal) and the request would eventually time out. This stopped after i added this line in the body-parser initialization:

```
 type: 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

Now, the console.log form the route appears in the terminal, but both parameters are empty.

Router.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name, req.body.password);
    res.send('posted');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    http_port = process.env.HTTP_PORT;

const http = require('http').createServer(app);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        type: 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        extended: true,
    })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('./backend/router'));
http.listen(process.env.PORT || http_port, () =>
    console.log(`App listening on port ${http_port}`)
);
```

Form from index.html

```
                      <div>
                        <form method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Full Name</label>
                                <input
                                    name="name"
                                    type="text"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="Enter your name"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input
                                    name="email"
                                    type="email"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input
                                    name="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                <input
                                    name="password_confirm"
                                    type="password"
                                    required
                                    placeholder="Confirm your password"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div id="button" class="row">
                                <button
                                    formmethod="POST"
                                    formenctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                                    type="submit"
                                >
                                    Sign Up
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you make sure in networking tab the request is being send with necessary data?

Comment: I have checked, and in the request, under "Form Data" every value i am trying to send is present

Comment: <form method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> is missing action <form action="<EXPRESS_ENDPOINT>/signup" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> try this. <EXPRESS_ENDPOINT> replace this with your server url.

Comment: I have tried that before, and i did another test now, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to fix it, but i managed to find a workaroud. The info from the form is also in request.fields, so i am going to use that instead of request.body. I still would like to know why it doesn't work as normal though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type: 'x-www-form-urlencoded'` in your parser and add `action="http://localhost:3000/signup"` to your form

Comment: This makes the route unreachable now. The route does not get triggered if type: x-www-form-urlencoded is removed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try 
`app.use(bodyParser.json());` 
instead of 
`app.use(express.json());`

Comment: This does not make a difference unfortunatelly